# How to run an AWS Lambda function across an entire organisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-organizations, aws-config

I have AWS account and want to delete the access keys across all child accounts which have not not been accessed > 90 days.

I created a Lambda function which [lists all access keys](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_access_keys) and usernames in an account, using the Boto3 IAM client. Then I [delete the access keys](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.delete_access_key). This works fine in a single account.

The problem is we want to run this Lambda across 300+ accounts.

1. How to run this Lambda function across that many accounts?

Known methods:

-> [configure a Lambda function to assume an IAM role in another AWS account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/)

-> Use AWS config to somehow run Lambda across that many accounts and delete only access keys which are not used for 90 days.

I'd appreciate some guidance on this :)

Comment: Why do you need a Lambda function for that? AWS Config already has a managed rule `iam-user-unused-credentials-check` and remediation method `AWSConfigRemediation-RevokeUnusedIAMUserCredentials` that can do this for you automatically

Comment: Thanks for your  response. The reason this approach is needed is to remove programmatic access only. 
"AWSConfigRemediation-RevokeUnusedIAMUserCredentials runbook revokes unused AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) passwords and active access keys. This runbook also deactivates expired access keys, and deletes expired login profiles."

I would still like to keep the IAM password, but only delete the active access keys.

Answer (score 1):

A distributed approach would be to create a cloudformation template for your solution and deploy it as a "stack set" that deploys across all accounts.

This prevents having to setup a bunch of cross account roles, and a long running lambda script that cycles through all accounts.